# How do I run an npm command with a different version of node using nvm?

Tags: node.js, nvm

Tried these:

```
✗ nvm run 9 npm start 
Running node v9.10.1 (npm v5.8.0)
module.js:545
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/foo/work/grid-styled/npm'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)



✗ nvm run 9 npm -- x0 dev docs/App.js
Running node v9.10.1 (npm v5.8.0)
module.js:545
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/foo/work/grid-styled/npm'
```

I can get it to run by calling the bin directly:

```
nvm run 9 node_modules/.bin/x0 dev docs/App.js
```

But it would be better to just call npm. Seems possible [but the nvm docs don't address this use case.](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you use `nvm run` you are executing node on a specific version, so: 
`nvm run 9 npm start`  is equivalent to `node npm start`  (with version 9 of node). That's the reason for the error.

You should use `nvm exec` instead, that is for executing a command on specific version, for instance:

```
$ nvm exec 10 npm -v
Running node v10.0.0 (npm v6.0.0)
6.0.0
$ nvm exec 6 npm -v
Running node v6.10.3 (npm v3.10.10)
3.10.10
```